# How do I commit with git when receiving error: Waiting for your editor to close the file...?

Tags: git

I am new to git and I was able to use it successfully with my first repository but I just added another and now I am unable to commit to either repository. When I make the commit I receive this message:

```
throg@throg-VirtualBox:~/repos/git_test$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot run code--wait: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'code--wait'
Please supply the message using either -am or -F option.
```

I thought it might be problems with Visual Studio Code but I receive the same message when using that.

Comment: Note that the "Waiting" hint message is not itself an error—Git always prints that, in case it shows up. Depending on your editor and terminal and other setup, you may not *see* that message after a successful commit; or you might see it *while* Git waits, and it explains why nothing is happening at that point; or you might see it immediately after you finish editing the commit message, in which case it was not a useful hint, but won't look like an error either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command

```
git config --show-origin core.editor
```

It will print the config file path and the value of core.editor.

It seems you have set the wrong value `code--wait`. It should be `code --wait`. If it's the case, open the config file and edit the wrong value, save and quit.